# Problem connecting to the Database

Tags: oracle

This is my Oracle DB :

```
Server :      hp805
Listener :    7633
SID :         idopd
ServiceName : serv01
Login :       ikr_adm
Passwd :      ikr_adm_01
```

How do you connect to this DB ?

Comment: With which interface do you want to connect? Java/JDBC, ODBC, C, C#, .Net, PowerBuilder, Delphi?

Comment: DB Visualizer.. I will use java But now I just want to create some tables using DB Visualizer

Answer (score 3):

The correct URL for a JDBC based connection would be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hp805:7633:idopd
```

But that information should be available in the DbVisualizer manual and is definitely available in the Oracle manual.

**Edit**:
The description on how to setup a connection with the wizard is available here:
http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/main/doc/ug/getConnected/getConnected.html